# Get individual node at a specific index

Tags: c++, c, indexing, linked-list

i have a function that returns a node at a specific index but when the index is bigger than the length of the linked list i get a segmentation fault and i wrote a condition that will handle that

```
listint_t *get_nodeint_at_index(listint_t *head, unsigned int index)
{
        listint_t *temp;
        unsigned int i;

        i = 0;
        temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
                if (index == i)
                {
                        return (temp);
                }
                temp = temp->next;
                i++;
        }
        if (index < 0 || index > i)
                return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: Please remember that C and C++ are two *very* different languages. Only add the tag of the language you're actually working in.

Answer (score 1):

Calling code, which you haven't shared with us, is probably crashing when trying to dereference the NULL return value.

`head->next` must be `NULL` at end of list so you don't need a `i` vs `index` check as you will run out of elements if `index` is too large.  As arguments are passed by value in C you can just use the `head` argument instead of introducing the local `temp` variable:

`index < 0` is never true as `index` is an `unsigned int`.

```
listint_t *get_nodeint_at_index(listint_t *head, unsigned int index) {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; head; i++, head = head->next)
        if (index == i)
            return head;
    return NULL;
}
```

Here's a minimal program that demonstrate working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct listint_t {
    int data;
    struct listint_t *next;
} listint_t;

listint_t *get_nodeint_at_index(listint_t *head, unsigned int index) {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; head; i++, head = head->next)
        if (index == i)
            return head;
    return NULL;
}

void print(listint_t *p) {
    if(!p) {
        printf("NULL\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("%d\n", p->data);
}

int main() {
    listint_t *head = &(listint_t) { 0, &(listint_t) { 1, NULL }};
    print(get_nodeint_at_index(head, 0));
    print(get_nodeint_at_index(head, 1));
    print(get_nodeint_at_index(head, 2));
}
```

and example output:

```
0
1
NULL
```

The POSIX Standard 1003.1, B.2.12 Data Types, reserves the `_t` name suffix, btw, so I suggest you use a different name for your type.

Comment: thank you for the correction but i used your own function everything was working except when index is bigger than the length of the list just like my own function. I needed a function that will handle out of range.

Comment: I have a bit of unsolicited advise for you, and I hope you hear it because it will help you greatly.  "everything was working expect" is a contradiction, it either works or it doesn't.  It comes across as defensive, and it will cost you a lot of effort and time to overcome that.  We all make mistakes, especially industry it's a given, and we just want the problem fixed as soon as quickly as possible.  Listen to what your code tells you, if someone fails try to understand why.